# Ordenar List<T> usando regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, lista

Eu tenho um `List` de diretórios que é ordenado pelo nome:

```
List<DirectoryInfo> dirs = parentdir.GetDirectories().OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

O problema é que eu tenho pastas cujo nome são números separados por ponto (como se fosse a versão de um app **A.B.C.D** => **1.2.3.4**) e ai essa ordenação já não funciona, pois ordenando por nome a pasta **1.1.3.10** vem antes da **1.1.3.3**.

Existe alguma forma de ordenar isso com o auxílio de `regex`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode construir um comparador ([`IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) que compare strings contendo números, e passá-lo ao método `OrderBy`:

```
lista.OrderBy(c => c.Str, meuComparador)
```

Este comparador você pode fazer usando [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para repartir a string nas posições em que números forem encontrados:

```
Regex.Split(str, @"(\d+)")
```

- A regex `\d+` serve para indicar que queremos **achar sequências de caracteres com 1 ou + dígitos**:

  - `\d` significa **um dígito qualquer**
  - `+` significa **ache um ou mais do item anterior**
- O parêntese em torno do `\d+`, serve para indicar ao split, que o número deve ser mantido no array da repartição da string, de forma que possamos utilizá-lo na comparação. Veja como é diferente:

  ```
  Regex.Split("a123b", @"\d+")   => array ["a", "b"]

  Regex.Split("a123b", @"(\d+)") => array ["a", "123", "b"]
  ```

### A classe comparadora de strings contendo números

Implementei a classe, para ficar de presente para quem precisar no futuro. =D

```
public class ComparerStringComNumeros : IComparer<string>
{
    public static ComparerStringComNumeros Instancia
        = new ComparerStringComNumeros();

    private ComparerStringComNumeros() { }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var itemsA = Regex.Split(x, @"(\d+)");
        var itemsB = Regex.Split(y, @"(\d+)");

        for (int it = 0; ; it++)
        {
            if (it == itemsA.Length)
                return it == itemsB.Length ? 0 : -1;

            if (it == itemsB.Length)
                return 1;

            if ((it % 2) == 0)
            {
                // parte não numérica
                var strCompare = StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare(
                    itemsA[it],
                    itemsB[it]);

                if (strCompare != 0)
                    return strCompare;
            }
            else
            {
                // parte numérica
                var numCompare = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(
                    int.Parse(itemsA[it]),
                    int.Parse(itemsB[it]));

                if (numCompare != 0)
                    return numCompare;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Teste da classe acima, usando o `OrderBy`:

```
public void TesteDeOrdenacao()
{
    var l = new[]
        {
            "x0.2",
            "m1.2",
            "m1.04",
            "m10.0",
            "x1.2",
            "x1.04",
            "m10.0.0",
            "x1.2.2",
            "x1.04.8 a",
            "x1.04.8 b",
            "x1.04.8 c2",
            "x1.04.8 c3",
            "x1.04.8 c1",
            "x10.0",
            "m0.2"
        };

    var l2 = l.OrderBy(x => x, ComparerStringComNumeros.Instancia).ToList();

    // l2 irá conter:
    //
    // "m0.2",
    // "m1.2",
    // "m1.04",
    // "m10.0",
    // "m10.0.0",
    // "x0.2",
    // "x1.2",
    // "x1.2.2",
    // "x1.04",
    // "x1.04.8 a",
    // "x1.04.8 b",
    // "x1.04.8 c1",
    // "x1.04.8 c2",
    // "x1.04.8 c3",
    // "x10.0"
}
```

Como usar no seu código:

```
var dirs = parentdir.GetDirectories()
    .OrderBy(c => c.Name, ComparerStringComNumeros.Instancia)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Perfeito cara, muito obrigado. Olhando de primeira eu não consigo entender como fizeste isso (até porque não manjo de regex), mas eu vou usar essa classe pra poder estudar.

Comment: Editei! Adicionei mais informações sobre a regex, e como interpretá-la.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do @MiguelAngelo é boa num contexto geral - porém, neste contexto específico, existe uma solução *muito* mais fácil e adequada ao problema.

Tens que converter as strings para instancias da classe [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Version(v=vs.110).aspx). Como esta classe já implementa [`IComparable<Version>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), o `OrderBy` irá funcionar correctamente, sem precisar escrever código adicional.

```
parentdir.GetDirectories()
         .OrderBy(c => new Version(c.Name))
         .ToList();
```